# Does Xcode with version 7 and iOS 9 now allow iOS Simulator to authenticate and use System Proxies set up

Tags: ios, xcode, proxy, ios-simulator

As it is mentioned in Xcode 6.1 release notes

iOS Simulator does not support the use of network proxy servers that require authentication. (14889876)

So my query is does with Xcode 7 and latest iOS 9 what is the update! does it now allow to use system Proxy.

also the main query here is how to use Proxy network settings in simulator,

I have tried the followings

```
Settings -> Developer -> Allow HTTP services
```

&
SquidMan third party app to use proxy but no success.

Answer (score 0):

No.  That release note is still applicable in the latest versions (currently Xcode 7.2 beta).

Comment: thanks for the reply can you please tell me in that case, what is the alternative to use proxy via simulator.

Comment: There is no alternative.

Comment: Does this hold for Xcode 9 as well? I am facing the same issue